# Equicontinuous sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^{2}+(1-nx)^2}$ I need to prove that $(f_{n})_{n}$ is not equicontinuous! I try this problem by the definition of equicontinuous, but i cant do it. Can i help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You may note that $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(1/n)=1$. Now, you need to know what equicontinuity at $x=0$ means.

Comment: Together with the following lemma : let $(f_n)$ be a sequence $\mathcal{C}(X,R)$ with $(X,d)$ metric space, if $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous at $x$ then $\forall (x_n) \subset X$ such that $x_n\to x$, $f(x_n)-f(x)\to 0$.